# Summation $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}\frac{1}{\alpha^{2k+1}}\frac{B_{2k+2}}{\left(n-2k\right)!\left(2k+2\right)!}$

Tags: calculus, summation, bernoulli-numbers

For $\alpha, n \in \text{N}$

How do we Prove That,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}\frac{1}{\alpha^{2k+1}}\frac{B_{2k+2}}{\left(n-2k\right)!\left(2k+2\right)!}=\frac{\alpha}{n!\left(n+2\right)}-\frac{2\alpha-1}{2\left(n+1\right)!}+\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!\alpha^{n+1}}\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha-1}j^{n+1}$$
Where, $B_{n}$ is the $n$th Bernoulli Number.

The right side of the equation does not contain Bernoulli Numbers, I am guessing this used a property but I am not aware of that.

Comment: Notice that the sum on right side is related to the Bernoulli numbers as you can read in the comment and formula section of the OEIS sequence [A064538](https://oeis.org/A064538)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be using some conventions and formulae present on the Wikipedia page for the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Sum_of_powers) at the section the link goes to, but for self-containment (and also to adapt them to the current notations of this question) I'll write them down here as well:
Let $(B^{+}_n)_n$ et $(B^{-}_n)_n$ be the two conventions for the Bernoulli numbers, only differing at $n = 1$, where $B^{\pm}_1 = \pm \frac{1}{2}$. Since this'll play a role as well during the calculation, I'll also state the value of $B_0 = 1$.
Then, we'll consider as known the following formulae, aptly named Bernoulli's formulae:
$$(n+2)\sum_{j = 0}^\alpha j^{n+1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n+1} \binom{n+2}{k} B^+_k \alpha^{n+2-k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n+1} \binom{n+2}{k} B^-_k (-1)^k \alpha^{n+2-k}$$

Let's denote by $S_n$ the LHS of OP's expression. We finally have, multiplying it by $(n+2)!\alpha^{n+1}$ to introduce the missing binomial coefficients and correct the powers on $\alpha$ to use said formulae:
$$\begin{split} (n+2)!\alpha^{n+1} S_n &= (n+2)!\alpha^{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}\frac{1}{\alpha^{2k+1}}\frac{B_{2k+2}}{\left(n-2k\right)!\left(2k+2\right)!}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor} \alpha^{n+1-(2k+1)}B_{2k+2}\binom{n+2}{2k+2}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor} \alpha^{n+2-2k}B_{2k}\binom{n+2}{2k}\\
&= \sum_{k=2 \atop k \text{ even}}^{n+1} \alpha^{n+2-k}B_{k}\binom{n+2}{k}\\
&= \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{1 + (-1)^k}{2}\alpha^{n+2-k}B_{k}\binom{n+2}{k}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\sum_{k = 2}^{n+1} \binom{n+2}{k} B^+_k \alpha^{n+2-k} + \sum_{k = 2}^{n+1} \binom{n+2}{k} B^-_k (-1)^k \alpha^{n+2-k}\Bigg)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\sum_{k = 0}^{n+1} \binom{n+2}{k} B^+_k \alpha^{n+2-k} + \sum_{k = 0}^{n+1} \binom{n+2}{k} B^-_k (-1)^k \alpha^{n+2-k}\\
&\quad\quad\quad - \binom{n+2}{0}B_0^+\alpha^{n+2-0} - \binom{n+2}{0}B_0^-(-1)^0\alpha^{n+2-0}\\
&\quad\quad\quad - \binom{n+2}{1}B_1^+\alpha^{n+2-1} - \binom{n+2}{1}B_1^-(-1)^1\alpha^{n+2-1}\Bigg)\\
&= (n+2)\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha} j^{n+1} - \alpha^{n+2} - \frac{1}{2}(n+2)\alpha^{n+1}\\
&= (n+2)\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha - 1} j^{n+1} - \alpha^{n+2} + \frac{1}{2}(n+2)\alpha^{n+1}\end{split}$$
Redividing by $(n+2)! \alpha^{n+1}$, this then grants:
$$S_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)!\alpha^{n+1}}\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha - 1} j^{n+1} - \frac{\alpha}{(n+2)!} + \frac{1}{2(n+1)!}$$
We conclude by noticing that:
$$\frac{1}{(n+2)!} = \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)n!} = \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right) = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} - \frac{1}{n!(n+2)}$$
which implies that:
$$\begin{split}S_n &= \frac{1}{(n+1)!\alpha^{n+1}}\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha - 1} j^{n+1} - \left(\frac{\alpha}{(n+1)!} - \frac{\alpha}{n!(n+2)}\right) + \frac{1}{2(n+1)!}\\
&= \frac{1}{(n+1)!\alpha^{n+1}}\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha - 1} j^{n+1} + \frac{\alpha}{n!(n+2)} - \frac{\alpha}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{2(n+1)!}\\
&= \frac{1}{(n+1)!\alpha^{n+1}}\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha - 1} j^{n+1} + \frac{\alpha}{n!(n+2)} - \frac{2\alpha - 1}{2(n+1)!}\end{split}$$
which is what was desired.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

We first try to evaluate

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}
\frac{1}{\alpha^{2k+1}} \frac{B_{2k+2}}{(n-2k)! (2k+2)!}$$

and we note that this is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n
\frac{1}{\alpha^{k+1}} \frac{B_{k+2}}{(n-k)! (k+2)!}$$

We get with the EGF of the Bernoulli numbers

$$\sum_{k=0}^n
\frac{1}{\alpha^{k+1}} \frac{1}{(n-k)!}
[z^{k+2}] \frac{z}{\exp(z)-1}
\\ = [w^n] \exp(w) \sum_{k\ge 0}
\frac{1}{\alpha^{k+1}} w^k
[z^{k+2}] \frac{z}{\exp(z)-1}.$$

Here we have extended to infinity due to the coefficient extractor.
Continuing,

$$\alpha [w^{n+2}] \exp(w) \sum_{k\ge 0}
\frac{1}{\alpha^{k+2}} w^{k+2}
[z^{k+2}] \frac{z}{\exp(z)-1}
\\ = \alpha [w^{n+2}] \exp(w) \sum_{k\ge 0}
w^{k+2}
[z^{k+2}] \frac{z/\alpha}{\exp(z/\alpha)-1}
\\ = [w^{n+2}] \exp(w) \sum_{k\ge 0}
w^{k+2}
[z^{k+2}] \frac{z}{\exp(z/\alpha)-1}
\\ = [w^{n+2}] \exp(w)
\left[\frac{w}{\exp(w/\alpha)-1}
- \alpha + \frac{1}{2} w\right]
\\ = - \frac{\alpha}{(n+2)!} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{(n+1)!}
+ [w^{n+2}] \exp(w) \frac{w}{\exp(w/\alpha)-1}.$$

Now observe that

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha-1} j^{n+1}
= (n+1)! \sum_{j=0}^{\alpha-1} [w^{n+1}] \exp(jw)
\\ = (n+1)! [w^{n+1}] \frac{\exp(w\alpha)-1}{\exp(w)-1}
\\ = (n+1)! [w^{n+2}] \frac{w\exp(w\alpha)-w}{\exp(w)-1}
\\ = - \frac{B_{n+2}}{n+2}
+ (n+1)! [w^{n+2}] \frac{w\exp(w\alpha)}{\exp(w)-1}
\\ = - \frac{B_{n+2}}{n+2}
+ \alpha^{n+1} (n+1)!
[w^{n+2}] \frac{w\exp(w)}{\exp(w/\alpha)-1}.$$

Merge the two to get

$$- \frac{\alpha}{(n+2)!} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{(n+1)!}
+ \frac{1}{\alpha^{n+1} (n+1)!}
\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha-1} j^{n+1}
+ \frac{B_{n+2}}{\alpha^{n+1} (n+2)!}.$$

To conclude recall that OP asks for the upper limit
$\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor$ rather than $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor.$
These are equal when $n$ is odd but when $n$ is even the top term is
missing. This term is (substitute and simplify)

$$\frac{1}{\alpha^{n+1}} \frac{B_{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$$

so that we have

$$- \frac{\alpha}{(n+2)!} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{(n+1)!}
+ \frac{1}{\alpha^{n+1} (n+1)!}
\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha-1} j^{n+1}
\\ + \frac{B_{n+2}}{\alpha^{n+1} (n+2)!} (1-[[n\;\text{even}]]).$$

However when $n$ is odd we get zero from the Bernoulli number and when
$n$ is even we get zero from the parenthesized term containing the
Iverson bracket. We have shown that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{\large \begin{array}{c|c}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor}
\frac{1}{\alpha^{2k+1}} \frac{B_{2k+2}}{(n-2k)! (2k+2)!}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{n+2-2\alpha}{(n+2)!}
+ \frac{1}{\alpha^{n+1} (n+1)!}
\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha-1} j^{n+1}.
\end{array}}}$$

Remark. For the initial segment of the series about zero
of $z/(\exp(z/\alpha)-1)$ we write

$$\alpha \frac{z/\alpha}{\exp(z/\alpha)-1}
= \alpha \frac{B_0}{0!} + \alpha \frac{B_1}{1!} \frac{z}{\alpha}
+ \cdots = \alpha - \frac{1}{2}  z + \cdots$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I would love to accept both of the answers, but I can only do one :(